# K8s V1.24.3 the kublete is crashdown,show The connection to the server master:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

enviroment:centos7.0
I want to build K8s cluster that have 3 nodes,one of them is the master;every pod'status is running,but there is a pod name test-claim is pending, the pvc is pending status:
[image]

then I eidt the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml ,added a row

```
    - --feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false
```

the problem is appear :

```
The connection to the server master:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

is there any problem I was missing?why the kubelet is crushdown? could somebody answer this question? thanks a lot previously.

this the content about kube-apiserver.yaml, could find some synatic error?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 192.168.199.13:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.199.13
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.1.0.0/16
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false
    image: registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-apiserver:v1.24.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.199.13
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.199.13
        path: /readyz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.199.13
        path: /livez
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
status: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally find the solution don't need to edit the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml file to add this row:- --feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false;this is not help for me. the solution is :

```
1、docker pull vbouchaud/nfs-client-provisioner
```

Status: Downloaded newer image for vbouchaud/nfs-client-provisioner:latest
docker.io/vbouchaud/nfs-client-provisioner:latest

2、editing your deployment.yaml file
vi deployment.yaml

change the images from quay.io/external_storage/nfs-client-provisioner:latest to docker.io/vbouchaud/nfs-client-provisioner:latest
[image]
3、
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml

finally the pvc'state would change from pending to bounding like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1. Your Pod & PVC is in pending state because you haven't created a relevant PV. Your `StorageProvisioner` for some reason isn't creating the `PersistentVolume` automatically so you need to create it manually.
2. Kube API server isn't working due to which the kubectl is facing `connection refused` error after adding the`--feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false`. Maybe, there's some syntatic error in the modified manifest. Can share the contents of your `kube-apiserver.yaml` file?

Comment: thanks a lot,this comment can't paste the yaml,I put my kube-apiserver.yaml under the answer.

Comment: the wired thing is when I delete the row: --feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false; My kubectl.service run success again, firstly I thought The syntatic problem.but I can't find it

Comment: **I've tested this feature-flag with k8s v1.23.0 and it works fine. kube-apiserver takes couple of seconds to restart during which the kubect received connectivity error**. Your manifest also looks okay to me. May I ask why were you adding this flag in the 1st place?

Comment: I want use the application nfs-client-provisioner to make the NFS Server using for K8s's volume and provided pv function, and I get all source file from: git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage.git ; then I found pvc report the error:waiting for a volume to be created ;someone says the K8s already discard the SelfLink, that cause the pvc pending state.so I add this row hope can use the SelfLink to make pvc is bounding

Comment: `SelfLink` has nothing to do with `PVC` not getting bounded. The issue (apparently) is related with `StorageProvisioner` not creating a `PV` automatically based on the `PVC`.

Comment: thanks very much! your answer give me idea to solve this problem.I found the pvc pending reason is the nfs-client-provisioner images; I change the images from quay.io/external_storage/nfs-client-provisioner:latest to docker.io/vbouchaud/nfs-client-provisioner:latest ;then it works!! my pvc's state is bounding now. Thanks again!!